# F# windowsforms application with custom class

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-scripting

I have a button class derived from Button()
with position attribute

```
namespace fgame15

open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

module Game15Button =
   type Game15Button(position:Point) as button =
      inherit Button()
      member this.Pozition = position
```

This is my main module that shows a form
It is compiling without any errors, but 
not displayed form with button

```
namespace fgame15

open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

module Main = 
 do
    let form = new Form(BackColor = Color.Pink , Text = "My Window Application")
    let btn=new Button()
    btn.Text <- "Ok"
    form.Controls.Add(btn)
    Application.Run(form)
```

Prints the following warning

```
Warning 1   Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run
```

Comment: Your second example works just fine.

Comment: Yes, the second example works fine but when i added the button class it doesn't work

Comment: You might need to move the file with the button class so that it appears before the main module (file order matters in F#)

Comment: Thank you very much @TomasPetricek, working like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not your last file fs in the project, it will not execute when the app starts. You can re-order files using Alt+Up/Alt+Down in VS, or using the context menu on each file.